# Keys missing as designer property of UC

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I'm starting to code a custom keyboard for my company, and I'm not sure why I don't have access to all keys in the designer. This seems like it should be very simple. One example key is Escape, but there are others.

New Project ->
 
right-click -> add new -> UserControl
**UserControl1.vb**

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Private _myKey As Keys
    Public Property MyKey() As Keys
        Get
            Return _myKey
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Keys)
            _myKey = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Build -> Form1 designer -> Drop UserControl1 onto Form1.vb

**Form1.vb [Design]**
->Select UserControl11
Properties -> Misc -> MyKey 
try to set to Keys.Escape (or any number of others).

The available keys list is fairly verbose, but absolutely not complete.

What is the right way to do this? I would much prefer find a solution that allows me to do this via the designer than having to do this on load programmatically.

The below works, but again, I don't understand why I can't do this in the designer:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        UserControl11.MyKey = Keys.Escape
    End Sub
End Class
```

I know I can define my own Enum and get it, but that's so much time for something that should probably just work with .net. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, great question with clear repro directions.

It's strange behavior for sure. Maybe someone has an explanation.

This workaround might do the trick though

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Private _keyCode As Integer

    Public Property KeyCode As Integer
        Get
            Return _keyCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _keyCode = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property MyKey As Keys
        Get
            Return CType(_keyCode, Keys)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Keys)
            _keyCode = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

You can set KeyCode in the property pages to the integer value of Escape in System.Windows.Forms.Keys for instance, which is 27.

[image]

at which point, MyKey actually displays Escape. Not sure why it doesn't show up in the list.

The values can be found on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.71).aspx

Note: you can also just type Escape in MyKey. Adding KeyCode gives a nice other option though.

Comment: Very strange to have to do this to get around it. Definitely works, thanks much.

Comment: I'm hoping for Hans to come explain why this happens, and possibly allude to some ancient feature of VB6

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` Enum in a decompiler, you will see that it is decorated with both a `TypeConverter` and `Editor` attribute.  These attributes are controlling what you can do in the WinForms designer as they are inherited by your `MyKey` property.

```
<Flags, TypeConverter(GetType(KeysConverter)), Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ShortcutKeysEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", GetType(UITypeEditor)), ComVisible(True)> _
Public Enum Keys
```

If you want to present the `Keys` Enum with the default Enum UI, you will need to decorate your property with its own `TypeConverter` and `Editor` attributes that tell the designer to use the default editor and the `Enum` type converter (this converter allows conversion between the `Enum` and `String` representation) instead of the ones declared on the `Keys` type.

```
<System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute(GetType(System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter))>
<System.ComponentModel.Editor(GetType(UITypeEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor))>
Public Property MyKey() As Keys
```